# Finding all the visible elements using the given root

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following code

```
var a = $('<div><div></div></div>');
a.css("visibility", "visible");
a.find("* :visible");
```

I receive an empty array `[]` as a result instead of a `div`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if an element is visible, it must be inserted into the DOM. You also don't need the `*` selector. Try this:

```
var a = $('<div><div></div></div>'); // create an element
a.css("visibility", "visible");
$("BODY").append(a) // Add the element to the DOM first
a.find(":visible")

alert(a.find(":visible").length); // displays '1'
```

Comment: Without the * selector, the query will return the outer element instead of the inner element.

Comment: @Guffa I've tested and that is not the case. With and without the `*` return 1 element.

Comment: That's because it happens to be only one element inside the outer element. The point is that the queries return *different* elements. The result is not the same without the `*`.

Comment: You are correct in that the result is different without the `*` - sorry that was a mistake in my previous comment. However, the `*` should definitely NOT be used in the selector for this - fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/9SFxM/

Comment: Yes, you are right, the * should not be used, because the `find` method is used, which searches *inside* the selected elements.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't added the element to the page, so it's not sized yet. Elements with zero size are not considered visible.